# Correct the position of a rectangle after scaling it.

Tags: geometry

I have 2 rectangles that can scale in size. They both scale from there own center point. The blue rect can be positioned any where on the canvas.

[image]

After upscaling I get something like this.

[image]

However I want the blue rectangle to respect its original position relative to the red rectangle. So my question is what formula can I use to correct the blue rectangle position. The Image below reflects the corrected position.

[image]

The following values are given. The position(X), width(A) and height(B) of the red rectangle. The position(Y), width(C) and height(D) of the red rectangle.

Comment: From the drawings it looks like the distance between the centers stays the same after the transformation is applied. Is this the case?

Comment: The rectangles scale from there centers so yes the distance between the centers stay the same in the first transformation. However after the scaling I want to do a new transformation thats sets to the position of the blue rect to relatively the same position as it was.

Comment: It's not clear what "respect the original position" means for you. You want to keep fixed the distance between the boundaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the centers of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. The vector connecting them can be computed as
$$ v = y-x. $$
If $s$ is the scaling factor, to achieve what you need you just need to modify the center of $Y$, namely replacing $y$ with the new center
$$ a + s\cdot v = (a_1, a_2) + (s\cdot v_1,\; s\cdot v_2). $$
See the pictures below for the geometric intuition.

[image: Original]
[image: After scaling]
[image: After the fix]