# Calculate inner rectangle new top left position after outer rectangle is scaled

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a rectangle inside a rectangle, like this:

[image: before scaling]

After the outer rectangle is scaled, I'd like to scale the inner rectangle in proportion to outer as well (I can already do this). What I'm having trouble with getting the new position (x,y of top left) of the inner rectangle while still in proportion to the outer before scaling.

What formula should I use to calculate it?
Would be extremely grateful for any help. Thanks!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention this: the top left x,y of the inner rectangle is not based on the outer rectangle(red) but rather their container(black). The same applies to the outer rectangle.

Comment: Apply the same scaling to the rectangle's center or corner coordinates (taken relative to the center or corner of the external rectangle).

Comment: @CiaPan Hey, thanks for responding, I actually forgot to mention something, both x,y of the rectangles are based on the container they're in, so multiplying the scale to the inner rectangle would make it proportional to the container and not the outer rectangle. I updated the question and the picture. Hope you can help with this again, thanks

Comment: Do these answer your question? — [Correct the position of a rectangle after scaling it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601186/correct-the-position-of-a-rectangle-after-scaling-it) — [How do I calculate the new x y coordinate for a rectangle when centering it within a rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703228/how-do-i-calculate-the-new-x-y)

Comment: I'll take a look at them, thanks

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you so much! I got my answer by referring to the second link you gave and modifying it a little bit. You have no idea how frustrating this was for me so my thanks are truly sincere.

Comment: @CiaPan so sorry to bother you again but I was so tired last friday I wasn't able to read the post of the 2nd link properly, it was actually to center the inner rectangle in the outer rectangle, that's not what I wanted, I wanted to keep the inner rectangle in the same relational position to the outer while the outer is scaled. I'm guessing I'd have to edit the /2 part into what I want, unfortunately I have no idea what to replace it with. I wonder if you could help me with this